ListPlot3D ignores points
First time asking something here, so apologies if I omit important info.
I am trying to make a 3D-Plot of some data with three variables. It works fine with ListPointPlot3D where all the data points appear. However, when I want to add a surface to the plot using ListPlot3D, it omits some of the points when making the surface. Any ideas on how to fix that? For example, is there a way to add a surface to the ListPointPlot3D (could not figure it out via the Documentation)?
Here is the data and code I used. Running it shows the difference between the output form ListPlot3D and ListPointPlot3D:
data = {{
   "", 0., 100., 200., 300., 400., 500., 600., 700., 800., 900., 
    1000., 1100., 1200., 1300., 1400., 1500., 1600., 1700., 1800., 
    1900., 2000., 2100., 2200., 2300., 2400., 2500.}, {0., 30.431674, 
   30.436406, 30.3939078, 30.3885018, 30.3859194, 30.3785295, 
   30.3913672, 30.3908276, 30.3860606, 30.382112, 30.3782662, 
   30.3762457, 30.3681495, 30.3570149, 30.3687323, 30.3667491, 
   30.3621421, 30.3559528, 30.3341971, 30.3581964, 30.3530625, 
   30.3389515, 30.3611992, 30.3658148, 30.3540573, 30.3494379}, {0.1, 
   28.301129, 28.2606493, 28.2163389, 28.2295299, 28.2196044, 
   28.2422022, 28.2265167, 28.2892315, 28.2297996, 28.2529821, 
   28.2480194, 28.2872235, 28.2537029, 28.2627824, 28.2851377, 
   28.2913484, 28.2719218, 28.2933903, 28.3132547, 28.2806226, 
   28.3321887, 28.2897352, 28.3033786, 28.2793018, 28.2737947, 
   28.3251885}, {0.5, 28.5904409, 28.5761866, 28.5856073, 28.5737402, 
   28.5737402, 28.5960202, 28.5830984, 28.5797876, 28.5703216, 
   28.5651337, 28.5803062, 28.567981, 28.5749809, 28.5750388, 
   28.5698299, 28.5679798, 28.5761242, 28.5507966, 28.570572, 
   28.5694304, 28.5758816, 28.561853, 28.5576052, 28.5619443, 
   28.5803026, 28.5511511}, {1., 28.6891664, 28.6728928, 28.6666995, 
   28.6505341, 28.6908389, 28.671922, 28.6933317, 28.696113, 
   28.6743894, 28.6775366, 28.6570415, 28.6908259, 28.6714672, 
   28.7041239, 28.6596847, 28.660527, 28.6731657, 28.6649395, 
   28.6734451, 28.6596771, 28.6653448, 28.6817074, 28.6616352, 
   28.6726241, 28.6711828, 28.6657464}, {2., 28.5224754, 28.5335592, 
   28.5031167, 28.4983362, 28.4914227, 28.4942017, 28.4676732, 
   28.5222669, 28.4986851, 28.5186424, 28.4868419, 28.4899224, 
   28.5236624, 28.4716448, 28.4958665, 28.4860997, 28.5022206, 
   28.5000563, 28.5214293, 28.4996445, 28.4960731, 28.4752613, 
   28.4735921, 28.5088998, 28.4712892, 28.5032114}, {5., 28.6663328, 
   28.6243762, 28.6566291, 28.6265353, 28.634729, 28.6118285, 
   28.6323285, 28.6065243, 28.619485, 28.6162401, 28.630221, 
   28.6303733, 28.6090725, 28.6287603, 28.6460444, 28.6267277, 
   28.653891, 28.6294364, 28.629312, 28.5957318, 28.6345417, 
   28.6551767, 28.6451685, 28.5682688, 28.6346419, 28.6221346}, {10., 
   28.4646266, 28.4583578, 28.4463844, 28.4548304, 28.4521635, 
   28.4497783, 28.4062102, 28.4409063, 28.4760579, 28.4192557, 
   28.4067773, 28.4487062, 28.4298715, 28.4149376, 28.4289029, 
   28.4519735, 28.4142138, 28.4183247, 28.4173531, 28.43997, 
   28.4401472, 28.4023973, 28.4240851, 28.397826, 28.4207159, 
   28.3850058}};

tab = Catenate@
  Table[{data[[1, 2 ;;]][[x]], Transpose[data][[1, 2 ;;]][[y]], 
    Transpose[data][[2 ;;, 2 ;;]][[x, y]]}, {x, 
    Range@Length@data[[1, 2 ;;]]}, {y, 
    Range@Length@Transpose[data][[1, 2 ;;]]}]

ListPlot3D[tab, PlotRange -> All]
ListPointPlot3D[tab, PlotRange -> All]

Here is how the plots appear for me:


Cheers!

Which points do you think are missing?

I've added images of the plots to the post. It can bes seen that for the ListPlot3D some points are not included in the surface for y between 1500 and 2500. On the other plot they can be seen.

ListPlot3D has to set up an interpolation scheme. It may be failing to interpolate. I have this problem all the time. One possibility is the very different ranges in both directions.

@Hugh has supplied the answer.  If you include tab[[All, 1]] = tab[[All, 1]]/100; which gets all 3 dimensions roughly on the same scale, the result is what is expected.

Great, thank you! The data was in seconds, so I followed your suggestions and did it in minutes instead. This fixed it as you predicted :)!
